# Gradle sync fails in a Kotlin + Spring Boot tutorial project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm a beginner in Java, Kotlin. I'm trying to build a web backend using Kotlin, SpringBoot and IntelliJ.

I'm trying [this Kotlin+SpringBoot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/), but Gradle sync fails.

The following error occurs.

[image]

[image]

I also tried to remove `~/.gradle` and sync it again, but it still fails.

How can I get Gradle sync to succeed?

**Environments**

- IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.7 (Community Edition)
- Build #IC-181.5540.23, built on November 12, 2018
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b43 x86_64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- macOS 10.14.6

Comment: What is your gradle version?

Comment: Please share your project for investigation.

Comment: @MadhuBhat I'm using Gradle 6.3.

Comment: @amenbo I've seen similar error for gradle 6 in IntelliJ Idea 2018. And it got resolved when I upgraded the IntelliJ to 2019 version. You can try that if possible.